# JQuery and php-Problem with file_get_contents() after $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to load a error.html-file after clicking a html-button. Therefore, I have a website with a button and the corresponding click-event.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../../server/check.php",
            data: "login=granted&user=user&site=overview",

            success: function(msg)
            {
                alert(msg); 
            }
        });
```

In this click event I use $.ajax to call a check.php-script that should load my html file via file_get_contents(). Here's the complicated php-Code:

`<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('../client/manage/login/error.html');
echo $homepage;
?>`

Now the problem is that error.html isn't loaded, instead the html-code is returned to the $.ajax call. If i type the url of the check.php directly into the browser, it works.

I know there are several approaches how to load a html file, but I need to do it exactly this way. Actually, there are several other sites that I want to load via this php-script.

Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks much.

EDIT: OK, I try to be a bit more specific. I've successfully implemented a login-system. This system consists of two html-input fields, one for the username and one for the password. Both are checked against a database. If both are correct, the user is allowed to access some protected html-sites.

Now I wanted to avoid that a user can directly put the urls of the protected sites into the browser's address bar; therefore I created a .htaccess file and forced every request of a protected html site with the help of mod_rewrite to be redirected to the check.php.
Here's the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /simulation/client/manage 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.html$ ../../server/check.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You see, all protected html files are in /simulation/client/manage, this is the path where are all protected sites are in. If a user wants to redirect to one of them, he is sent to check.php with the corresponing site he or she wants to access.
Here's the php code:

```
if(strcmp($_POST["login"],"granted") == 0)
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST["user"];
}
else if(strcmp($_POST["logout"],"logout") == 0)
{
    session_unset();
    $_SESSION=array();
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
        $homepage = file_get_contents('../client/manage/login/error.html');
        echo $homepage;
}
else
{
        $homepage = file_get_contents('../client/manage/'.$page.'.html');
        echo $homepage;
}
```

So far, so good. In this check.php I check if session-variables are set. They are set only if a user has successfully logged in. If not, the error.html is loaded.
This all works well, if a user types the url of one of the protected pages into the browser and is not logged in, file_get_contents loads the error.html page, otherwise one of the protected pages is loaded.

The only problem is that if I call the script via $.ajax, nothing is loaded.

Comment: you said "instead the html-code is returned to the $.ajax call" what HTML code exactly?

Comment: The complete code of the website, including doctype and all other things that are declared in the website.

Comment: alert(msg) shows me the following:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
        Error
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Can you have it print out the entire error? There could be a problem when trying to run file_get_contents() from an ajax call. For example: it could be a problem with your URL path that is different when you run it from the ajax calling page in the client folder than when you access the server folder php script directly in the browser.

Comment: I tried to use the full path: url: "http://localhost/simulation/server/check.php" But this leads to the same result

Comment: The only way the html from error.html will get 'loaded' onto your page is by inserting it into the DOM somewhere.  You could redirect them to the error.html page in the PHP code.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to replace a complete html-site with the code that is returned from my ajax-request? Unfortunately, $(document).replace(msg); does not seem to work.

Comment: Ok I tried to use header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); in my php script to do a redirect but again, if I call the script with ajax, it does not work. On the other hand, f I call the script directly, it works. Why?

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behavior of an AJAX call.  You are requesting the contents of that URL (your PHP script).  If I understand your need correctly you could insert the returned html into the body of the page:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../../server/check.php",
            data: "login=granted&user=user&site=overview",

            success: function(msg)
            {
                $('body').html(msg);//ADDED LINE
            }
        });
```

Comment: thats incorrect. If I understand your answer correctly, you are saying the ajax call would return the PHP script itself? If so, this is incorrect, it would return the output of the PHP script.

Comment: I had this idea, too, but for me this doesn't seem a very elegant solution. The site also includes a lot of meta-data so this is not so ideal.

Comment: No citizen, Jake is right, just the code of the html-page is returned.

Comment: I know, Im not saying that the code of the HTML page isnt returned, Im saying that the script should run and show your output anyway, and that it should never show you the PHP script itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish then.  You can insert the returned content anywhere.  You can create a modal, insert it into a new div near the top of your regular content and then fade it out.  We either need more information or you can get creative.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my opinion the best solution for this problem is to read the file with read_file() in php and catch the html-code in the browser.
Then I user the following three commands in the ajax success callback function:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../../server/check.php",
        data: "login=granted&user=user&site=overview",

        success: function(msg)
        {
           document.open();
       document.write(msg);
       document.close();
        }
    });
```

This solution is nearly the same as Jake's, but here you can replace the entire document.
Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Please note that anyone can edit Javascript, and thus pass in login=granted and gain entry that way.  Unless you're planning on changing how your code works, there is a **HUGE** security hole here.